# highcharts dynamic plotlines

Tags: dynamic, highcharts

I am encountering a problem, how to update the plotlines(on YAxis) dynamically? Specifically, I need to calculate a max, min and average value for a period of the chart, then setup the 3 lines which they stand for. How can I do that? 
many thanks!

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.addPlotLine ; http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.removePlotLine

Comment: Find my idea using these functions below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple example of how to update plotlines dynamically.

- It has one data series which can be updated by the press of a button.
- When pressing the second button, plotlines will be added or removed+redrawn according to the data of the series.
- If you want to use a subset of data points, feel free to work on the function `getKPIByData` accordingly, or change the `data` argument.

http://jsfiddle.net/hsL4pwsh/12/

```
;$(function() {
    var curActiveData = 1;
    var addedPlotlines = false;
    var data1 = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];
    var data2 = [31.9, 73.5, 117.4, 29.2, 109.0, 181.0, 212.6, 137.5, 225.4, 199.1, 91.6, 11.4];
    var getKPIByData = function(data) {
        function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
            return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
        }
        function getMinOfArray(numArray) {
            return Math.min.apply(null, numArray);
        }
        var minRate,
            maxRate = 0,
            rate,
            i,
            avgRate,
            totalRate = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            totalRate += data[i];
        }
        return {
            minRate: getMinOfArray(data),
            maxRate: getMaxOfArray(data),
            avgRate: totalRate / data.length
        };
    };
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        },
        series: [{
            data: data1
        }]
    });
    // the button action
    var $button1 = $('#addPlotlines'),
        $button2 = $('#updatePlotlines'),
        chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    $button1.on("click", function() {
        var curData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < chart.series[0].data.length; i++) {
            curData[curData.length] = chart.series[0].data[i].y;
        }
        var result = getKPIByData(curData);
        if (addedPlotlines) {
            chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('min');
            chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('max');
            chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('avg');
        }
        chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
            color: 'green',
            width: 2,
            id: "min",
            value: result.minRate
        });
        chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
            color: 'red',
            width: 2,
            id: "max",
            value: result.maxRate
        });
        chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 2,
            id: "avg",
            value: result.avgRate
        });
        addedPlotlines = true;
    });
    $button2.on("click", function() {
        var newActive = (curActiveData == 1) ? 2 : 1;
        console.log(newActive);
        chart.series[0].update({
            data: (newActive == 1) ? data1 : data2
        });
        curActiveData = newActive;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But what i am trying to do is update the plotlines in a dynamic graph which, doesn't need buttons to update

Comment: By using buttons, I was just trying to demonstrate the functionality which is necessary. Feel free to use any event handlers instead of button clicks to call these functions, namely `addPlotline()` and `removePlotline()`. The KPI calculation (min,max,avg) can be adapted according to your needs also.